# Firebase Twitter oAuth callback not working for Swift ios13

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, twitter-login

I have followed the instructions on https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/twitter-login to a T for Swift and I get the web popup to authorise the App I created on Twitter Dev, the callback is called and then the webview sits on an empty page of about:blank. Nothing can be done but click the Done button which then results in a Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17058 "The interaction was cancelled by the user." 
Callback address is correct. I've used the Twitter Consumer API Keys as the keys to enter in the Firebase console.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you added twitterkit-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx value as a URL Scheme in the URL Types in the info.plist?
Also you need to add this twitterkit-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx value in the project Info URL Types section manually.

Comment: I'm not using the twitterkit that Twitter used to develop. It's been archived on github and is no longer supported. Just trying to use the firebase instructions.

Comment: When I click the Authorise App on the twitter Webview popup, it redirects to: https://myappname.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler?state=aBigJumbleOfNumbersAndLettersMixedCase&oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&oauth_verifier=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX. But then nothing happens and it just sits on a blank page not returning a credential.

Comment: I also tried with the instructions of firebase, but I failed to do so. Then I used the twitterkit and it is working in iOS 13 too. I knew it was deprecated, but I could not manage without this for the firebase twitter social login.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I was using twitterkit and am now needing to swap to something else.

Comment: Yes but I'm not exactly sure how now! Having a quick look I have this:

Comment: @JohnnyD I've followed the instructions on Firebase document but after I click on the button, nothing happens. Do I need to add any configs?

Comment: @JohnnyD  Having same issue. After authentication I'm not getting back to the app so the callback is not executed. Anyone found a workaround? I've followed Firebase's instructions and set the provider as global. No callback executed. Please help!

Answer (score 6):

For everyone who still has an issue with getting callback working, I managed to fix it. Sadly, you have to edit the method in the library (not the best way, but still. Bug was reported to firebase team). The method should look like the one below (you can find it in the file named FIROAuthProvider.m, line 125. I intentionally left commented lines, so you see the problem there... Hope it helps somebody :)

```
- (void)getCredentialWithUIDelegate:(nullable id<FIRAuthUIDelegate>)UIDelegate
                         completion:(nullable FIRAuthCredentialCallback)completion {
  if (![FIRAuthWebUtils isCallbackSchemeRegisteredForCustomURLScheme:self->_callbackScheme]) {
    [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException
                format:@"Please register custom URL scheme '%@' in the app's Info.plist file.",
                       self->_callbackScheme];
  }
//  __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
//  __weak FIRAuth *weakAuth = _auth;
//  __weak NSString *weakProviderID = _providerID;
  dispatch_async(FIRAuthGlobalWorkQueue(), ^{
    FIRAuthCredentialCallback callbackOnMainThread =
        ^(FIRAuthCredential *_Nullable credential, NSError *_Nullable error) {
          if (completion) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              completion(credential, error);
            });
          }
        };
    NSString *eventID = [FIRAuthWebUtils randomStringWithLength:10];
    NSString *sessionID = [FIRAuthWebUtils randomStringWithLength:10];
//    __strong __typeof__(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    [self
        getHeadFulLiteURLWithEventID:eventID
                           sessionID:sessionID
                          completion:^(NSURL *_Nullable headfulLiteURL, NSError *_Nullable error) {
                            if (error) {
                              callbackOnMainThread(nil, error);
                              return;
                            }
                            FIRAuthURLCallbackMatcher callbackMatcher =
                                ^BOOL(NSURL *_Nullable callbackURL) {
                                  return [FIRAuthWebUtils
                                      isExpectedCallbackURL:callbackURL
                                                    eventID:eventID
                                                   authType:kAuthTypeSignInWithRedirect
                                             callbackScheme:self->_callbackScheme];
                                };
//                            __strong FIRAuth *strongAuth = weakAuth;
                            [_auth.authURLPresenter
                                     presentURL:headfulLiteURL
                                     UIDelegate:UIDelegate
                                callbackMatcher:callbackMatcher
                                     completion:^(NSURL *_Nullable callbackURL,
                                                  NSError *_Nullable error) {
                                       if (error) {
                                         callbackOnMainThread(nil, error);
                                         return;
                                       }
                                       NSString *OAuthResponseURLString =
                                           [self OAuthResponseForURL:callbackURL
                                                                     error:&error];
                                       if (error) {
                                         callbackOnMainThread(nil, error);
                                         return;
                                       }
                                       __strong NSString *strongProviderID = _providerID;
                                       FIROAuthCredential *credential = [[FIROAuthCredential alloc]
                                               initWithProviderID:strongProviderID
                                                        sessionID:sessionID
                                           OAuthResponseURLString:OAuthResponseURLString];
                                       callbackOnMainThread(credential, nil);
                                     }];
                          }];
  });
}
```

Comment: You saved my time! Thank you!

Comment: Wow it's really the issue, thanks for helping! But how can this still be present?

Comment: This !! Thanks for the tip ! I had the issue that the callback wasn't even called at all, even thought I followed all the steps from the Firebase tutorial. This fixed the issue instantly.

Comment: This is not the correct solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

For me there was no need in framework modifications.

As stated in a [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4414) on GitHub: provider property should be

> declared at a class or global level

So I just moved its initialisation out of a function.

Before:

```
class AuthViewController: UIViewController {
   private func signIn() {
      let provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "twitter.com")
      provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { 
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

After:

```
class AuthViewController: UIViewController {
   private let provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "twitter.com")
   private func signIn() {
      provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { 
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got stucked in about:blank page for days, tried all the above but not working, solved by add following code in AppDelegate

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let twitterhandeled = Auth.auth().canHandle(url)
    return twitterhandeled
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution looking at [@tommy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75386461/18716297)'s answer.

If you're developing a SwiftUI app just add to your top level view:

```swift
.onOpenURL { url in
    Auth.auth().canHandle(url) // Required for twitter login callback
}
```

Probably if your app is not using SwiftUI then [@tommy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75386461/18716297) code should work:

```swift
// Inside your AppDelegate
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let twitterhandeled = Auth.auth().canHandle(url)
    return twitterhandeled
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I resolved this question but not entirely sure how now. I believe it was because the callback wasn't being issued and thus not picked up by the app. The callback wasn't issue due to the authentication and I believe because I hadn't created the terms of service and privacy policy. So make sure you have done that in the Twitter dev page.

In the twitter dev page, the callback link is: https://yourApp.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler
You'll find this in your firebase authentication settings when you enable twitter.

Ensure you have in info.plist LSApplicationQueriesSchemes an array of:
twitter
twitterauth

In your swift file:

```
var provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "twitter.com")
```

Your button action:

```
@IBAction func onCustonTwitterButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    MyAppsCoreServicesScripts.logoutSocial() // My logout routine.
    provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in
    if let error = error {
        MyAppsCoreServicesScripts.showError(prefix: "Twitter Login",error: error, showMsg: true)
        } else if credential != nil {
            self.firebaseLogin(credential!)            
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck! Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what did you assigned in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes?

Answer (score 0):

Invalid declaration of the OAuthProvider can be issue but, for me problem was that `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` was set to `false`. You can simply solve that by setting `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` to `true`, but if you want to have that proxy disabled you can do that but you need to add `Auth.auth().canHandle(url)` to the `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>)` method in `SceneDelegate` (for iOS 13+) and everything will work without problem.